# the combobox dropdown list is so small that an updown arrows appear beside it

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, dropdownlistfor

I have comboboxes that was built on the OWL I moved them to MFC and I faced alittle problem, the dropdown list of the combobox is so short that it shows only one item and you can navigate to the other items by using udown arrows like in the picture
[image]

the image on the left shows the short and incorrect one, the one on the right shows the release version that is working well.
what can cause this problem? and hoe to fix it. think it is style issue

Answer (score 4):

Open dialog template in Resource Editor. Select combobox by mouse. Click on the "Down Arrow" element in the right part of the combobox (in your case it may be left part, according to localization). Then resize the combo to required height - in this state it resizes dropdown list. Build application and test dropdown list height at runtime - it should be OK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4cta1x1t.aspx

See also: CB_SETMINVISIBLE message - allows to resize dropdown list size programmatically. I have never use it in my programs, though, so this is just a hint.

Comment: the problem is that the two instances are using the same resources, the one on the left and the one on the right and sometimes the combo is being created in the runtime.

Comment: Try CB_SETMINVISIBLE message: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It worked fine but I need to change the default behaviour of it to be normal